# Coffee script not loading after assets:precompile for my ActionCable chat function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, precompile

I am building an chat function in my Ruby on Rails(v5.0.0) site. I had it finnaly working unteal I ran bundle exec rake assets:precompile for pushing it to production.

I can't seems to get it working again! And it's pretty stupid...

**The problem**

It looks like the files arn't loading anymore, none of the scripts are running on production or development.
Now when you enter a comment, you get an error of course cause there is no coffeeScript that takes over your request.

**routes**

```
  mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
```

**application.hml.haml**

```
    = action_cable_meta_tag
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require cable.coffee
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require script.js
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require cable
//= require metronome.js
//= require private_pub
//= require sticky.js
//= require waveform.js
//= require waveform.extensions.js
//= require timeline.js
//= require turbolinks
//= require_self
//= require_tree .
//= require serviceworker-companion
//= require addtohomescreen.js
//= require dragend.js
```

**cable.coo**

```
# app/assets/javascripts/cable.coffee
# Action Cable provides the framework to deal with WebSockets in Rails.
# You can generate new channels where WebSocket features live using the
#  rails generate channel command.
#
# Turn on the cable connection by removing the comments after the require statements
#   (and ensure it's also on in config/routes.rb).
#
#= require action_cable
#= require_self
#= require_tree ./channels

@App ||= {}
App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer()
```

**/channels/index.coffee**

```
App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer("/cable")
```

**/channels/rooms.coffee**

```
jQuery(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  messages = $('#messages')
  if $('#messages').length > 0

    App.global_chat = App.cable.subscriptions.create {
        channel: "ChatRoomsChannel"
      },
      connected: ->
        # Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server

      disconnected: ->
        # Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server

      received: (data) ->
        $('#messages_' + data['chat_room_id']).prepend($(data['message']).fadeIn(400))
        $(document.getElementById('notification').src = 'https://www.jammify.com/metronome_low.mp3';notification.play());

      send_message: (message, chat_room_id, user_id, receiver_id) ->
        @perform 'send_message', message: message, chat_room_id: chat_room_id,  user_id: user_id, receiver_id: receiver_id

      $('.new_message').submit (e) ->
        $this = $(this)
        textarea = $this.find('#message_body')
        chat_room_id = $this.find('#message_chat_room_id')
        if $.trim(textarea.val()).length > 1
          App.global_chat.send_message textarea.val(), chat_room_id.val(), $('#messages_' + chat_room_id.val()).data('user-id'), $('#messages_' + chat_room_id.val()).data('receiver-id')
          textarea.val('')
        e.preventDefault()
        return false
```

You guys need anyting else?
It looks like the whole rooms.coffee is not loaded at all.

Comment: Have you run `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` on the server?

Comment: Possibly because `config.public_file_server.enabled`, in `config/environments/production.rb`, is set to `false` (it may use an environment variable). Check that, and set it to true if it's not already, then try again.

Comment: Thanks for answering, unfortunately none of the suggestions work :(